# Communicate between Android Activity and Java Class

Tags: java, android, interface, global-variables

I have to communicate between an Android Activity and another Java class. In a very, very stripped down version of what I want, I want the Java Class to run, and when it's done, set some information. To get a more specific idea of what I want to happen:

```
Activity {

CallJavaClass(); // Doesn't return anything, would be very bad form
GetInfoFromJavaClass() // Once the JavaClass has finished what needs to be done

}
```

What I could do:

1. Set a global variable in JavaClass that my Activity can access. I'd rather not do it this way, as I would have to implement some kind of OnChangedListener on that object in the JavaClass.
2. Use an Interface with Setters/ Getters. The problem with this is my JavaClass is a Singleton, and most of its methods are static, which is a no-go when working with an Interface.
3. Create a separate class that handles these variables. I would rather keep it simple and not have to use a bunch of different classes to do this, though.

So what do you think would be the best solution? If needed (and probably will be), I can provide more information about what exactly I want done. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like something you could use AsyncTask for http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

then again, it depends on the specifics of what you're going for

Comment: Right, an asynctask would be good for this situation. But when it finishes and I have to set information in onPostExecute, it still looks like I'll have to set a global variable of some kind if interfaces are a no-go.

Comment: Using a global variable isn't bad practice, but do keep it private and use a getter method to access it. Seems like an acceptable straightforward solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask should resolve your problem:

```
private class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // do something before starting the AsyncTask
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // do what you want to do               

            return false;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) 
        {
            super.onPostExecute(success);
            // do something right after you finish the "doInBackground"

        }


    }
```